# Turn if/else statement into switch statement

Tags: javascript

I have found an example on http://www.w3schools.com/ of how to create [a responsive navigation bar](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav)

The example has a little bit of JavaScript in the form of a if/else statement. I would prefer to use a switch statement.

However, my switch statement does not work when i click the icon and does not provide any errors.

Example's JS code:

```
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
```

My Switch statement:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
switch (x) {
    case "topnav":
        x.className += " responsive";
        break;

    default:
        x.className = "topnav";
}
```

Comment: make it switch (x.classname) rather than switch (x) --- and I was a day late and a dollar short. lol

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing `x`:

```
switch (x)
```

But the original code is comparing `x.className`:

```
if (x.className === "topnav")
```

Switch on `x.clasName` instead:

```
switch (x.className)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are very close!

Just swap in `x.className` in your `switch(x)` statement, and you're good to go:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
// use x.className below...
switch (x.className) {
    case "topnav":
        x.className += " responsive";
        break;

    default:
        x.className = "topnav";
}
```